# Actualizar Select2 Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, select2

Tengo un select2 sencillo:

```
<select id="material" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%;"  aria-hidden="true">
   <option value="1">PC</option>
   <option value="2">Raton</option>
   <option value="3">Teclado</option>
   <option value="4">Monitor</option>
</select>
```

Su declaración:

```
$('#material').select2();
```

El componente funciona como se esperaba.

El problema es que cambio su valor mediante:

```
$("#material").val("3");
```

Y compruebo que su valor cambia con `alert($("#material").val());` pero sigue mostrando el valor anterior.

Es decir que no actualiza el componente, ¿Cómo resolver esto?

Comment: hice [un fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efu9kLbg/) y cuando asignas un valor el `alert` lo detecta

Comment: @lois6b si el valor cambia, pero el aspecto no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deberías añadir tras cambiar el `value`, un `change()` para que los cambios de valor se vean afectados visualmente en el Dropdown.

```
$("#material").val("3").change();
```

o

```
$("#material").val("3");
$("#material").change();
```

Comment: eso era, muchas gracias!

Comment: de nada, me alegra ser de ayuda. Un saludo